# Autolayout constraints does not appear in the Size Inspector (Xcode 6.4)

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing an iOS app in Swift using autolayout, everything looks good but in a specific View Controller I have a Collection View and when I set the constraints for that element their does not appear in the Size Inspector View.

[image: Size Inspector].

But constraints appear in the Document Outline.

[image: Document Outline]

Finally when I run the project the collection view does not handle the constraints and does not show the view correctly.

### Edited

Attached the image that show the constraints that I created for the Collection View.

[image: Constraints]

Comment: You have shown that there is a Constraints item in the document outline but you have not shown what's in it.

Comment: @matt sorry, I just added the screenshot with the constraints